# Why are only specific transaction types accepted into the mempool?

Tags: transactions, script, transaction-verification

In the Bitcoin Mainnet, only specific transaction types are accepted:

> Bitcoin uses a scripting language to specify (and satisfy) the encumbrances, thereby allowing a whole host of transaction types. Although many transaction types can be represented in the scripting language, only a limited number of standard transaction types are actually accepted by the network and the miners. ([source](https://www.quantabytes.com/articles/a-survey-of-bitcoin-transaction-types))

What is the point of equipping Bitcoin with a scripting language, while only accepting a pre-defined set of transaction types? What harm could be caused to the network by accepting valid transactions with an arbitrary locking script?

Comment: This information seems very outdated (or wrong).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any script can be used in P2SH/P2WSH technique. Using arbitrary scripts in transaction outputs cause grows of UTXO database and other problems.